# Exception com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61

Tags: java, maven, dropwizard, java-17, guice-3

Getting this Error log on Running , my DropWizard Application .
I am using JDK 17 and have verified for the same .
Please help

Already checked .
My java version is 17.0.9

```
mvn version : Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.6/libexec
Java version: 17.0.9, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "13.5.1", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"

Dropwizard version : 3.0.1
```

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2048)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3850)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3874)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4799)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4805)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.StackTraceElements.forMember(StackTraceElements.java:71)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Messages.formatSource(Messages.java:241)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Messages.formatSource(Messages.java:220)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Messages.formatMessages(Messages.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.CreationException.getMessage(CreationException.java:50)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:397)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:496)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4222)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:835)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintWriter.println(Throwable.java:779)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:670)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:736)
    at io.dropwizard.core.cli.Command.onError(Command.java:69)
    at io.dropwizard.core.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:82)
    at io.dropwizard.core.Application.run(Application.java:94)
    at com.flipkart.ads.server.InternalAPIApplication.main(InternalAPIApplication.java:107)
```

Comment: Already checked .
My java version is 17.0.9

Comment: Do you get the error while compiling or while running your application

Comment: I get the error while running my Application . I have tried everything not able to find that what might break @Jens

Comment: Looks like you run the application with a jre lower than java 17

Comment: I have verified my JRE is 17.0.9 only

Comment: How has you verified it?